# Estimating $p(x)$ with a nonparametric method

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, pattern-recognition

"Pattern Classification" book I study that in nonparametric methods we need to estimate $p(x)$, and we don't want just the averaged version of it. They give an example of theoretical procedure to achieve estimation of $p(x)$ but don't understand it.

> Suppose we use the following procedure. To estimate the density at x,
>   we form a sequence of regions $R_1$, $R_2$,.. containing $x$ - the first
>   region to be used with one sample, the second with two, and so on. Let
>   $V_n$ be the volume of $R_n$, $k_n$ be the number of samples falling in $R_n$,
>   and $p_n(x)$ be the $n$-th estimate for $p(x): p_n(x)=(k_n/n)/V_n$. **[Eq.7]**
>
> If $p_n(x)$ is to converge to $p(x)$, three conditions appear to be
>   required:
>
> - $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} V_n = 0$;
> - $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} k_n = \infty$;
> - $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} k_n/n = 0$.
>
> The first condition assures us that the space averaged $P/V$ will
>   converge to $p(x)$, provided that the regions shrink uniformly and that
>   $p(\cdot)$ is continuous at $x$. The second condition, which only makes sense
>   if $p(x) = 0$, assures us that the frequency ratio will converge (in
>   probability) to the probability $P$. The third condition is clearly
>   necessary if $p_n(x)$ given by [Eq.7] is to converge at all. It also says
>   that although a huge number of samples will eventually fall within the
>   small region $R_n$, they will form a negligibly small fraction of the
>   total number of samples.

**My problem:**

1. I don't understand why do these conditions are necessary?
2. If 2nd condition holds, how does it coexist with the 3rd? I mean that $k_n = \infty$, so $\infty/n = 0$ ?

Comment: Your second point is a bit confused. $k_n$ is a sequence of $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So $\infty/n$ does not make sense. $k_n/n$ converges to zero means that the sequence $k_n$ goes to infinity less fast than $n$.

Comment: I recommend reading chapter 1 (especially section 4) of the book "Elements of Large-Sample Theory" of Lehmann. It contains a very intuitive explanation of that aspect that is particularly relevant to statistics.